# why am i only getting the first row value in array "row" in the below code. i need all the values corresponding to the query

Tags: php, for-loop, return, echo

```
  $s = $conn->prepare($q);
  $s->execute([$tagIdValue]);
  $d = $s->fetchAll();
  return $d;

function x($d) {
    foreach ($d as $row) {
      $val = $row["id"];
      $cont = trimContent($row);
      return $row;
    }
  }
```

i have a query , which returns all the values in the table and a function to convert it into an assosiate array. But only getting the first row in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ur using return inside loop, it only take first value and return it.

```
  $s = $conn->prepare($q);
  $s->execute([$tagIdValue]);
  $d = $s->fetchAll();
  return $d;

function x($d) {
    $arr =[]
    foreach ($d as $row) {
      $val = $row["id"];
      $cont = trimContent($row);
      array_push($arr, $val)
    }
   return $arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your return outside the loop so only it returns only the first loop

```
function x($d) {
   foreach ($d as $row) {
     $val = $row["id"];
     $cont = trimContent($row);
     return $row;
}
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of previous ones. Also, without implementing the suggestion. Simply did a copy-paste of  part OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are returning the result set in the loop.

So, only the first row is returned from the loop.

As, in the first iteration, `return` statement is encountered, so, that function will return and control will get out of the function.

And next iterations will not loop over the result set.

We need to create an array before loop,

append results to that array

and return the array.

Corrected Code:

```
$s = $conn->prepare($q);
  $s->execute([$tagIdValue]);
  $d = $s->fetchAll();
  return $d;

function x($d) {
 $array = array();
    foreach ($d as $row) {
      $val = $row["id"];
      $cont = trimContent($row);
       $array[] = $row;
    }
 return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead writing a return inside a loop, replace that line with an array push or array shift function.

Once the loop has ended return the final result obtained from array_push/array_shift.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return outside the loop :

```
$s = $conn->prepare($q);
$s->execute([$tagIdValue]);
$d = $s->fetchAll();
return $d;

function x($d) {
  $arr =array();
  foreach ($d as $k=> $row) {
    $val = $row["id"];
    $cont = trimContent($row);
    $arr[$k] = $row;
  }
  return $arr;
}
```